# Solving $x(x+3)(x+4)(x+1) = 34$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> How would you solve this?
>   $$x(x+3)(x+4)(x+1) = 34$$

I tried to regroup, and to expand, but I don't know how to end it, and I think I am going to a bad way of solving it.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $$y=\dfrac{x+x+3+x+4+x+1}4=?\iff x=y-2$$

$$34=(y-2)(y-2+3)(y-2+4)(y-2+1)=(y^2-2^2)(y^2-1^2)$$ which on rearrangement is a quadratic equation in $y^2$

Comment: Thank you, but i tried another method. I grouped them like [X(x+4)][(x+3)(x+1)] = 34
then i got (X^2+4x)(x^2+4x+3) = 34 after t = x^2+4x and then substitution

Comment: @iftwMZ, Great. That'll also work as $$x+x+4=x+1+x+3$$  Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it pays to use standard methods.

The expanded polynomial is

$$x^4+8x^3+19x^2+12x-34.$$

Then we depress it with $x=y-2$ and get

$$y^4-5y^2-30$$ which is biquadratic.